# Notepad++ delete words by list

Tags: notepad++

I have a list with 100 words. I have different files with text and want to delete all words in theses texts which are in the list.

Is there a plugin or other possibility in notepad++ to do this?

Comment: You'd better write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

This is something I'd do with a script, but if you can't use one, I suppose you can create a very long regex that concatenates all the words in the list using alternation, like:

```
word1|word2|word3|word4
```

and then you could do a Replace (Ctrl-H), Find in Files, Search Mode: regular expression, and replace the searched regex with nothing. Click on Replace in Files and it should do it. Just make sure all the text files are in the same directory, and specify it from the options.

If it turns out to be too slow you can split the regex in more than one list of words, that is, instead of having only one that contains all the 100 words, you can have, say, 5 that contain 20 words each. I've never tried such a long regex, but actually it shouldn't be a big deal for Notepad++. It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Manual long way, not fully suitable. Using *Replace* command with Regex search.

1. Prepare [Regex](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions) pattern with list of words like: `\<(word1|word2|word3)\>`. Where `\<` & `\>` matches the start & end of a word respectively.
2. Invoke *Replace* command from menu. Use regex search option with pattern above. And use empty string as replacing string.

---

Notes.

- Regex pattern with words could be made by similar method (search/replace) in other text file.
- After words replacing there will be unwanted spaces. They need additional processing.